# How to check the repeated characters in a string

Tags: c#, forms

I am creating a program that filters and check if the word is existing in a dictionary. The problem is how to know if the word has repeated characters.

For example:

```
string string1 = "sorrrrrrry";
```

that string does not exist in the dictionary but if you remove repeated r it will be "sorry".

I am using hunspell to check if the word exist in the dictionary. Any solution please? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you're doing this. 'sorrrrrry' doesn't exist in the dictionary, so why would it matter if it did after removing repeated characters. Does 'dddddddiiiiiiiiicctiiiiooonnnnnnnnnnnnaryyyyyyyy" exist in the dictionary?

Comment: When you look up a word in a dictionnary and it doesn't exist. What you do? You look it up with another way of spelling it. I don't think you should try to start doing that. What if a word (I don't have any example in mind now) like `abbc` exist and also `abc`?

Comment: @im_a_noob; `God` and `Good` are a good example.

Comment: the reason why I need to check the string because I am analyzing the emotion of the tweets. There is a study that the addition of the same letter within a word can be a emotion markers.

Comment: @im_a_noob: If it does not exist in the dictionary I remove the word but there are instances they typed 'scarrrrrry'. Thats why I need a solution for that.

Comment: You can preprocess your dictionary to remove all repeated letters.

Comment: @MMakati Maybe you could try to find duplicate letter with a <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx">regular expression</a> 
But then after the logic is pretty mutch going to be fuzzy. Maybe with sql you could get something near. I was was thinking like search a word that start with individual letter (ex : scarrrrrrry) you would look up _scar_ and then you could refilter with the end of the word _y_ so that would cut down the number of words by a great number

Answer (score 2):

For your case what you can do is:

- replace the repeated characters but 2 => "**sorry**"
- look if the word exists on the dictionary
- if not, replace the 2 repeated characters by 1 character => "**sory**" (if you have for example "**caat**")
- look if the word exists on the dictionary

Using the regex `(\w)\1+` (matches repeated characters) and replacing the first time by `$1$1` (2 repeated matched characters) and the by `$1`

```
string input = "sorrrrrrry";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\w)\1+");

string replacement = "$1$1";
string res = regex.Replace(input, replacement);
Console.WriteLine(res);
//will output => sorry

replacement = "$1";
res = regex.Replace(input, replacement);
Console.WriteLine(res);
//will output => sory
```

**Warning**
This can give some results **BUT** it has some limitations and can produce unexpected results:

- you need to handle all the combinations if more than two characters are repeated: if you have "**soooorrrry**" it will give you 1. "**soorry**" and then 2. "**sory**", so the algorithm **will not work**.
- what to do with the case "gooood", is it "good" or "god" ?

Comment: Maybe it could be possible to process by this way but process only one multiple letter at time. Ex: sooooorrrrry -> soorrrrry check if exist. soorrrrry -> soorry check if exist. keep going until all characters are single (ex sory). This still isn't fail proof but might give a bit better result. If this fail it could be done again but starting with the reverse

Comment: Yes, something like htat, the key now is to find all the possible combinations

Comment: Maybe the op just want to know if the word exist or not. In this case your exemple _"gooood", is it "good" or "god" ?_ doesn't really matter. He could confirm/infirm that.

Comment: @im_a_noob you are right the, this point is not a limit but just a case to consider.

Comment: Thank you for giving some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You only can try to guess by several fuzzy logic methods which word is the one, wich could match SOME in the dictionary and, if more than one is found, show a list.

Perhaps You know, how a smartphone keyboard tries to help You.

This way is more or less the proper one ( during typing ) not after.

But after is also possible, but needs more effort.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into storing the dictionary in Lucene.Net and using its loose matching capability to match the words.